# Ball growth function for $Z^n$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, geometric-group-theory

in this book: https://issuu.com/yilongzhang/docs/piotr_w._nowak__guoliang_yu-large_s in the Example 3.1.9. it is said that for group ($Z^k$,+) we have:

$|B(0,n)|=\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}+\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+$ lower order terms,

where we consider $Z^k$ with word metric and standard generating set, B(0,n) is centred ball.

I don't see why is it true.
Could you help me solving this problem?

**My attempts:**
We want to know what is the number of integer solutions of inequality: $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_k| \le n$, so maybe first find the number of integer solutions of $|x_1|+|x_2|+...+|x_k|=n$. Then we have possibilities:
If $x_i\neq0$ then there are $2^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ possibilities, if $x_i=0$ for only one i, then there are $2^{k-1}\binom{k}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-2}$ possibilities and so on. So $|S(0,n)|=2^k\binom{n-1}{k-1}+2^{k-1}\binom{k}{1}\binom{n-1}{k-2}+...+2^{1}\binom{k}{k-1}\binom{n-1}{0}$. But how to sum this? Or maybe there is another, more tricky solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path, but there are a few tricks to employ:

The number of sums of positive integers whose sum is at most $n$, i.e., sums
$$
y_1+\cdots+y_k\leq n
$$
where $y_i\geq 1$ is the same as the number of sums of $k+1$ positive integers whose sum is $n+1$, i.e.,
$$
y_1+\cdots+y_k+z=n+1.
$$
Using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of such integers is $\binom{n}{k}$.  This can be written out as 
$$
\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}=\frac{n^k}{k!}+\cdots
$$
Here, the $\cdots$ represents lower powers of $n$.  Since all the $y_i$'s are positive, and we can look at the positive or negative version of each $y_i$ ($y_i=|x_i|$, so $x_i=\pm y_i$), this gives $2^k$ different possibilities for the $x_i$'s given the $y_i$'s.  This results in 
$$
\frac{(2n)^k}{k!}
$$
for the leading term.  If you write out the coefficient of $n^{k-1}$ from this expression and add in the terms where *exactly* one of the $y_i$'s is $0$ (using a similar argument), you will get the next term.

More precisely, for the next term, we consider the coefficient of $n^{k-1}$ in the numerator.  The coefficient of this term will be $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}-i=-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$, resulting in 
$$
-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\frac{2^kn^{k-1}}{k!}=-(k-1)\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}.
$$
Using the same argument as above, but with *exactly* one of the $x_i$'s equal to $0$, the leading term is 
$$
\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}.
$$
Then, since there are $k$ possible $x_i$'s to equal $0$, the entire expression becomes
$$
-(k-1)\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}+k\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}=\frac{(2n)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!},
$$
as desired.

If you're interested, this is related to the number of monomials of total degree at most $n$.  The additional $z$ is essentially a homogenization.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really like the solution!